# Decrement in Nested Loop Affects Outer Loop

Tags: php, arrays, random, html-table, nested-loops

Trying to display random numbers from 1-10, seven times per fourteen(rows) each number is assigned a different background color. I thought of using 2 nested loops, but it's not working as expected. The page loads for a long time then: "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in ..."

I tried to remove the decrement on the inner loop and the problem disappears but I don't get the expected results. Thanks in advance.

```
$colors = array("grey","white","yellow","red","blue","green","brown","purple","orange","black");
$previousNum = array();
$k = 0;
echo '<table>';
while ($k < 15){
    $k++;
    echo '<tr>';
    for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
        $randNum = mt_rand(1, 10);
        if(!in_array($randNum, $previousNum)){
            echo '<td style="background-color: '.$colors[$randNum-1].'; padding: 10px;">';
            echo $randNum;
            echo '</td>';    
            array_push($previousNum, $randNum);
        }else{
            $i--;
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Hope my code will help you out..

Comment: welcome..... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, hope this will help you out. The problem was that you were,

> **1.**  initializing array(`$previousNum = array();`) out of `while` loop

```
<?php

$colors = array("grey", "white", "yellow", "red", "blue", "green", "brown", "purple", "orange", "black");
$k = 0;

echo '<table>';

while ($k < 15)
{

    echo '<tr>';

    $previousNum = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
    {
        $randNum = mt_rand(1, 10);
        if (!in_array($randNum, $previousNum))
        {

            echo '<td style="background-color: ' . $colors[$randNum - 1] . '; padding: 10px;">';
            echo $randNum;
            echo '</td>';
            array_push($previousNum, $randNum);
        } 
        else
        {
            $i--;
        }
    }

    $k++;
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You were right to attempt to remove the decrement.  The decrement will negatively impact performance by running additional iterations.  Your posted attempt and the other answer do not correct this and unfortunately they run a minimum of 105 (7x15) condition statements -- this is not best practice, nor good for SO readers to learn from.  I've written a new optimized solution for you with no wasted declarations or iterations and added a white font coloration for dark backgrounds.

```
echo '<table>';
$whitefonts=['black','purple','brown','grey','blue'];  // for visibility
for($k=0; $k<15; ++$k){
    $colors=["grey","white","yellow","red","blue","green","brown","purple","orange","black"];
    echo '<tr>';
    for($i=0; $i<7; ++$i){
        $key=array_rand($colors);
        $color=$colors[$key];
        unset($colors[$key]);
        echo "<td style=\"background-color:$color;";
            if(in_array($color,$whitefonts)){echo "color:white;";}  //  for visibility
        echo "padding:10px;\">",++$key,"</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '<table>';
```